# Need help with another sharepoint validation formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, validation, list-validation

I am trying to validate the Ticket Number field for certain task types and i am trying to validate the Manager email field for certain task types.

My fields are like this:

**Task Type (Radio button selection)**:

Option 1,
Option 2,
Option 3,
Option 4,
Option 5

**Ticket Number (Single line of text field)**

**Manager Email (Multi Selection Field)**

I am trying to validate that if task types 1-3 are selected, that the ticket number cannot be blank.
But I am also trying to validate the manager email field is not blank for options 3-5.

My current formula validates the ticket number field for options 1 and 3, but I don't know how to add in the manager email field validation as well.

```
=IF(OR([Task Type]="Option 1",[Task Type]="Option 3"),IF([Ticket Number]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the type of Manager Email? is it multi choice field or multi allow people picker field?

Comment: It is a multiple choice field.

Comment: Ganesh is correct, we can't use Multi Choice field in validation formula to check whether it's empty or not

Comment: dang.  ok.  i guess i am stuck then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation of Manager Email field is not possible using list validation formula as multi-selection fields (Choice or Person/group) are not supported in SharePoint formulas.

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, you have to customize the list form using Power Apps to apply validation for Manager Email field.

Check below threads for more information:

1. [Validation for ComboBox](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Validation-for-ComboBox/td-p/576133)
2. [Validate dropdown/combobox is not blank](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Validate-dropdown-combobox-is-not-blank/td-p/108693)

Comment: I think requirement is to just validate whether manager email is added or not based on some condition i.e. Required validation,

Comment: Yes, but as it is a multiple selection field, it cannot be used in formula to check if it is empty or not.

Comment: I just want to check and make sure it is not blank, is that not possible with the multiple choice field type?

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible. In order to check if it blank or not you have to refer the column in formula, which is not supported in SharePoint.